# How can I extract data from a web page using IMPORTHTML() in Excel? Any clue will be welcome, thanks

Tags: qr-code

I need to extract to Excel Google sheets the TAG number of a Tequila bottle from the web page the QR takes you to.

HELP!!!

One example is:
WEB PAGE:   "https://siat.sat.gob.mx/app/qr/faces/pages/mobile/validadorqr.jsf?D1=4&D2=1&D3=6yNrTBO/HtepA3lHHvHfWC1NbBF9kF9F5c0000"

DATA TO EXTRACT: (Tag number)

2275222491

I've tried with IMPORTHTML(), IMPORTXML() but got only blank unswers.

I expect that any time the client of my app scans any Bottle QR, tha Tag number loads up to a cel in the Excel Google Sheets database.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Is it Excel or Google Sheets you mean ? What have you tried yourself so far ? Can you fetch **any** webpage using these functions ? Please also see [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Apart from that: the page does not return the data in the URL mentioned, but in a POST statement to a jsf, which needs a viewstate set. Could be hard to do in a spreadsheet.